# Cómo migrar mi base de datos en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, base-de-datos, migracion

Tengo una base de datos y agregué 2 columnas en ObtenSaldoPDV y quiero cambiar la versión de la base de datos de 1 a 2 pero si lo hago pierdo toda la información que hay y quiero saber como migrar la base de datos para actualizarla sin perder la info

````
        ObtenSaldoPDV.class,
        User.class,
        Anuncio.class,
        Producto.class,
        Compania.class,
        Servicio.class,
        Depositos.class,
        Rfc.class,
        Pdv.class,
        Banco.class
}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class RecargaDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    /**
     *
     * @return para la mayoria de las consultas de la aplicacion
     */
    public abstract RecargaDao recargaDao();

    /**
     *
     * @return userdao unicamente para el servicio en segundo plano que subirá el token fcm al ws
     */
    public abstract UserDao userDao();

}```
````

Comment: ¿Estás usando "Room" verdad?

Comment: Sip, agregué 2 columnas nuevas en la clase ObtenSaldoPDV

Comment: Que nombre y tipo son tus columnas ? @Juan

Comment: ```@Element(name = "Anuncio", required = false)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "anuncio", defaultValue = "null")
    private String anuncio;

    @Element(name = "Cambio", required = false)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "cambio", defaultValue = "null")
    private String cambio;```

Comment: Ok revisa mi respuesta Juan, debes usar ALTER TABLE para modificar la estructura de tu Tabla y agregar los dos nuevos campos @Juan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambia la version de la base de datos a la nueva versión 2:

```
@Database(entities = {
        ObtenSaldoPDV.class,
        User.class,
        Anuncio.class,
        Producto.class,
        Compania.class,
        Servicio.class,
        Depositos.class,
        Rfc.class,
        Pdv.class,
        Banco.class
}, version = 2, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class RecargaDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    /**
     *
     * @return para la mayoria de las consultas de la aplicacion
     */
    public abstract RecargaDao recargaDao();

    /**
     *
     * @return userdao unicamente para el servicio en segundo plano que subirá el token fcm al ws
     */
    public abstract UserDao userDao();

}
```

Crea tu clase para realizar la migración donde se agregarán las columnas a `ObtenSaldoPDV` usando `ALTER TABLE` :

```
static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) { //De versión 1 a 2
    @Override
    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        //* Modifica tabla ObtenSaldoPDV y agrega los campos nuevos.
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE ObtenSaldoPDV ADD COLUMN anuncio TEXT");
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE ObtenSaldoPDV ADD COLUMN cambio TEXT");
    }
};
```

Define la migración en tu clase `RecargaDatabase`, para que al migrar se agreguen las dos nuevas columnas a la tabla `ObtenSaldoPDV`:

```
@Database(entities = {
        ObtenSaldoPDV.class,
        User.class,
        Anuncio.class,
        Producto.class,
        Compania.class,
        Servicio.class,
        Depositos.class,
        Rfc.class,
        Pdv.class,
        Banco.class
}, version = 2, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class RecargaDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public static RecargaDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                RecargaDatabase.class, "recarga_database")
                .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2) //* Migración
                .build();
    }
 
    ...
    ...
    ...

}
```

Comment: MIGRATION_1_2 en que archivo lo defino y hay diferencia entre agregar las columnas directo en la clase a agregarlas por sql?